# Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR-flutter project

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm trying the **camera_deep_ar** plugin, I haven't wrote anything related to the package yet, I'm just trying to run the app after including the package. The app for now just include a home page with a button on the center that do nothing...

the app is not being able to be compiled, it gives me:

```
Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting
 AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file
 dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android
 Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error). The
 following direct local .aar file dependencies of the :camera_deep_ar project caused this error:
 C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\camera_deep_ar 0.0.2+3\android\lib\deepar0.aar
```

I've followed the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/camera_deep_ar) step by step

I think  there is a misunderstanding, maybe I missed something, the documentation says to write this line `-keepclassmembers class ai.deepar.ar.DeepAR { *; }` in the `proguard-rules.pro` file, so I created this file in the app folder `my_flutter_project/android/app/proguard-rules.pro` and wrote the line, then in the `build.gradle` I wrote this

```
buildTypes {
release {
    // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
    // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
```

I'm using

- vs code
- flutter sdk 3.7.12
- android sdk 32.1.0

so, what I've missed?